# Typed Function and Currying in Scala

Tags: scala

In Scala let's say I have a function like this:

```
def foo[R](x: String, y: () => R): R
```

so I can do:

```
val some: Int = foo("bar", { () => 13 })
```

Is there a way to change this to use function currying without "losing" the type of the second argument?

```
def foo[R](x: String)(y: () => R): R
val bar = foo("bar") <-- this is now of type (() => Nothing)
val some: Int = bar(() => 13) <-- doesn't work
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A variation on senia's answer, to avoid structural typing:

```
case class foo(x: String) extends AnyVal {
  def apply[R](y: () => R): R = y()
}

val bar = foo("bar")
val some: Int = bar(() => 13)
// Int = 13
```

Comment: You should really accept senia's answer, all I did was show a minor variant!  Besides Kudos, there's no material benefit in having a reputation over 20k.

Answer (score 14):

Functions can't have type parameters, you have to use a custom class like this:

```
def foo(x: String) = new {
  def apply[R](y: () => R): R = y()
}

val bar = foo("bar")
val some: Int = bar(() => 13)
// Int = 13
```

To avoid structural typing you could create custom class explicitly:

```
def foo(x: String) = new MyClass...
```

Comment: I think the second suggestion is better since it doesn't use structural types (which always come with reflection afaik?). At least I get the following feature warning: warning: "reflective access of structural type member method apply should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.reflectiveCalls visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.reflectiveCalls' or by setting the compiler option -language:reflectiveCalls."

Answer (score 2):

Not really a solution to your problem but just to point out that you can still use the second version of your function if you supply the type explicitly:

```
scala> def foo[R](x: String)(y: () => R): R = y()
foo: [R](x: String)(y: () => R)R

scala> val bar = foo[Int]("bar") _
bar: (() => Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> bar(() => 12)
res1: Int = 12
```